# can't install ks package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I tried to install package ks, using code

```
install.packages("ks-package")
library("MASS")
library("ks")
```

but got next error:

```
Warning message:
package ‘ks-package’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2).
```

After that I tried to use latest R version for this code, but again got error message:

```
Warning message:
package ‘ks-package’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

Please, help me to understand, why there is this error and how can I resolve it...

Comment: have you tried:  install.packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE)

Comment: `install.packages("ks-package")` looks for a package named **ks-package**, which is not what you say you want. If you want the **ks** package, just do `install.packages("ks")`.

Comment: thank you for answer, the problem was, that install.packages("ks") didn't worked, and I understood, that I need at first install.packages("ks-package"), but now I realized, that I need to install KernSmooth, mvtnorm, rgl and misc3d packages before, then install.packages("ks") works!

Answer (score 4):

With the most recent version of R, this should have succeeded:

```
install.packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE)
library("ks")
```

If you were using version 2.15.x, then yyou should have the tools for installing from source and then this should have worked:

```
install.packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE, type="source")
library("ks")
```

There are some mirrors that maintain copies of binary versions of packages for some OS, but you did not provide the needed information for specific comment on that issue.